# iptables does not seem to be applying SNAT to packets sent on a raw socket

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I'm writing packets from a user space program to my wireless interface wlan0.  I've set up a SNAT rule with iptables as follows

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.3
```

And it works for all normal traffic going out of my machine.

I am working on a program that uses raw sockets on layer 2 (ether).  Iptables is not applying SNAT to packets sent by this program.

Is there any way I can write packets in userspace from layer 2 and still have NAT applied to them?

Answer (score 0):

raw sockets get a copy of the original packet before modification (incoming). On outgoing it's reversed.

So in reality iptables gets bypassed as Raw sockets pretty much the IP stack, and therefore iptables because that's where it lives, and pass the packet straight to the application. then straight back out to whatever its connected to.

So in answer to your question, no you cant have NAT applied to them as they never go through iptables for the rule to be applied